# Bias in survival analysis: nice summary of all the different types and remedies

Tags: survival, references, cox-model, bias, observational-study

I am quite new to the field of survival analysis and am getting lost and confused with all the different types of bias that can occur, particularly in observational studies. For example, it appears the use of time-varying predictors can both reduce, but also incur bias! I realize that it will take intensive study to master this area, but I wondered if anybody would be so kind as to provide an answer (or suggest some references) which succinctly lists all the major kinds of bias and ways to handle them?

There are obviously lots of articles on specific types of bias but I was after more of a summary. Some kind of diagram / flowchart would also be good if such a thing exists.

Comment: This is a very broad question. Are you just interested in forms of bias specific to survival analysis? Or do you also need information about the types of bias that can bear found in any observational study?

Comment: Hi @EdM, I am most concerned with the major sources of bias when performing survival analyses on observational data (e.g. health registries and the like), rather than observational studies in general.